# Time series Analysis of household electric consumption using ARIMA and ARMA models

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R Language I tried with the following set of datas

```
Site Name   Utility Unit    Date    00:00   00:30   01:00   01:30   02:00 02:30 3-8
Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-03-2010  60.8    60.7    58.7    59.79   60.8    59.3 3-8
Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-04-2010  62.21   57.01   60.2    58.81   59.71   60.81
3-8 Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-05-2010  58.4    59.91   58.71   60.61   59.41   61.71
3-8 Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-06-2010  60.26   60.27   61.26   60.27   60.07   64.36
3-8 Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-07-2010  59.36   60.17   58.07   60.07   57.66   59.97
3-8 Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-08-2010  57.47   60.26   58.27   58.37   56.37   60.56
3-8 Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-09-2010  68.99   61.94   61.85   57.38   58.49   58.86
3-8 Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-10-2010  62.72   62.65   57.5    57.32   58.06   61.57
3-8 Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-11-2010  64.89   68.5    59.85   58.85   61.35   63.53
3-8 Whitehall
Place   Electricity kWh 06-12-2010  66.66   58.15   58.43   57.25   60.71   60.04
```

Code:

Please help me to plot data daily, weekly, monthly and quaterly, decomposition of addictive time series using time series

```
input <- read.csv("~/HomeElectricityForecast/data/input.csv")
View(input)
rdate <- as.Date(input$Date,"%m/%d/%y")
plot(input$X0.00 ~ rdate, type="l", col="red",xlab="Date", ylab="Units", main="Electricity Forecast - Line Graph")
box()
plot(input$X0.00 ~ rdate, type="p", col="green",xlab="Date", ylab="Units", main="Electricity Forecast - Point Graph")
# tsWeek <- ts(input$X0.00,frequency=7)
tsWeek <- ts(input[,2],frequency=53,start=c(2010,51))
tsDaily <- ts(input[,2],frequency=365,start=c(2010,20))
tsMonthly <- ts(input[,2],frequency=12,start=c(2010,30))
tsQuaterly <- ts(input[,2],frequency=4,start=c(2010,120))

library(forecast)
fit <- ets(tsWeek)
fc <- forecast(fit)
plot(fc)

y <- msts(input$X0.00, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
fit <- tbats(y)
fc <- forecast(fit)
plot(fc)

#ARIMA Weekly
fitWeek <- arima(tsWeek, order=c(1,0,1), list(order=c(0,1,0), period=53))
fc <- forecast(fitWeek) plot(fc)

#ARIMA Daily
fitDaily <- arima(tsDaily, order=c(3,1,3), list(order=c(0,1,0), period=330))
fc <- forecast(fitDaily)
plot(fc)

#ARIMA Monthly
fitMonthly <- arima(tsMonthly, order=c(1,0,0), list(order=c(0,1,0), period=11))
fc <- forecast(fitMonthly) plot(fc)

#ARIMA Quaterly
fitQuaterly <- arima(tsQuaterly, order=c(0,0,0), list(order=c(0,1,0), period=4))
fc <- forecast(fitQuaterly) plot(fc)

install.packages("fArma")
library(fArma)

#ARMA model
fitWeek_ARMA <- armaFit(~arma(1,1),data=tsWeek)
#Forecasting 10 weeks with test dataset.
predict(fitWeek_ARMA, newdata=testData_ByWeek,n.ahead=10,n.back=8, conf=c(80,95), doplot=TRUE)

#ARMA model Daily
fitDaily_ARMA <- armaFit(~arma(3,3),data=tsDaily)
#Forecasting daily with test dataset.
predict(fitDaily_ARMA, newdata=testData_ByDaily,n.ahead=10,n.back=8, conf=c(80,95), doplot=TRUE)

#ARMA model Monthly
fitMonthly_ARMA <- armaFit(~arma(1,0),data=tsMonthly)
#Forecasting Monthly with test dataset.
predict(fitMonthly_ARMA, newdata=testData_ByMonthly,n.ahead=20,n.back=8, conf=c(80,95), doplot=TRUE)

#ARMA model Quaterly
fitQuaterly_ARMA <- armaFit(~arma(0,0),data=tsQuaterly)
#Forecasting Quaterly with test dataset.
predict(fitQuaterly_ARMA, newdata=testData_ByQuaterly,n.ahead=20,n.back=8, conf=c(80,95), doplot=TRUE)
```

Please help for this

Comment: It would be helpful for you to 1) clarify your request for help, and 2) provide a reproducible example. Your post's title asks for help fitting an ARMA/ARIMA model, but the text above asks for help to "plot data daily, weekly, monthly and quaterly, decomposition". Can you provide the data, too?

Comment: @MarkS S Split the training data and test data for electricity consumption. after preprocessing over construct and decompose time series (daily, monthly, quaterly and monthly). Finaly building a model. Please refer the paper in the link  http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2013/IMECS2013_pp295-300.pdf

Comment: Splitting the data into training and testing pieces is an arbitrary decision that the analyst must make. You should start with the help files for some of the basic `R` functions like `decompose()`, `arima()`. You might also find the `auto.arima()` function in the `forecast`package helpful.

Comment: @MarkS give me some example

Comment: @carrotflowers Please help me. I am also using the same concept as you mention in stack overflow "ARIMA for power consumption time series, evaluation and Random Forests on time series" please share the code to ssureshsoundar@gmail.com. It will be useful for my UG project to be completed